# Maintaining Single database for whole web, ios, android

Tags: database

I need advice

I'm going to develop web application with mongodb as my backend. Later I have a plan to release ios and android app. Here my doubt is, Is it possible to connect to my mongodb which is deployed in some other server(aws) with swift(IOS) and Java(android).

Note:Assume I'm insisted to maintain single database deployed in aws.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok. You can develop your backend in restful style. Your web、ios、android can  communicate with the backend in `json`.